# Fortran Reading characters from file - no output

Tags: io, fortran

So I'm trying to understand some basic fortran IO and having trouble. I've written the following

```
program RFF
implicit none
! Variables
integer :: ierr    
character (:), allocatable :: Filename     
character (:), allocatable :: read_in 

! Body of RFF
Filename = 'string_test.txt' 
open(10, file=Filename, status='old', action='read',iostat=ierr) !What is iostat? 

do while (ierr.eq.0) !What is this do loop doing exactly? 
    read(10,'(A)',iostat = ierr) read_in !What does '(A)' mean? I know it's a format descriptor, but nothing beyond that 
    print*, read_in !Nothing gets output to the terminal here        
enddo

write(*,*) 'Press Enter to Exit'
read(*,*) 

!Is deallocating dynamically allocatable strings something I should do? 
deallocate(Filename) 
end program RFF
```

Which I've fed the very simple text file containing the word 'arbitrary' and nothing else. When I run the program, nothing crashes but nothing gets output to the terminal, either. Can someone help me understand what is going on? Note I've inserted a number of other questions into the comments of the code I've pasted. I'd like help understanding those as well.

Thanks

Comment: you should initialize `ierr=0` before the loop.   And no it it pointless to deallocate at the end of the program.

Comment: revising that, you should additionally *check* `ierr` after the open, or probably better don't use `iostat` in the `open` at all. It is usually poor practice to specify `iostat` then not do anything with the result.

Answer (score 1):

The real problem is that you must allocate `read_in` before you assign to it with `read`. One other thing: `iostat` is used to indicate either completion status or a possible error condition. See the code comments and official docs for other details (for example, [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/679813#08E2ACA0-323A-40A4-9AD4-4E0D90786846)).

Here is a working solution:

```
program main
    implicit none

    character(len=20) :: read_in                     ! fixed-length string
    character(len=:), allocatable :: word, filename  ! allocatable strings
    integer :: iostat_1, iostat_2                    ! status indicators
    integer :: lun                                   ! file logical unit number

    filename = 'read_test.txt'                       ! allocate on assignment
    iostat_1 = 0                                     ! initialization
    iostat_2 = 0

    open(newunit=lun, file=filename, status='old', iostat=iostat_1)
    if (iostat_1 == 0) then                          ! no error occurred
        do while(iostat_2 == 0)                      ! continues until error/end of file
            read(lun, '(a)', iostat=iostat_2) read_in
            if (iostat_2 == 0) then
                word = trim(read_in)                 ! allocate on assignment to trimmed length.
            endif
        enddo
        if (allocated(word)) then
            print *, "read_in:", read_in
            print *, "len(read_in)", len(read_in)
            print *, "Word:", word
            print *, "len(word)=", len(word)
        else
            print *, "Word was not allocated!"
        endif
    endif
end program main
```

Example output:

```
 read_in:arbitrary
 len(read_in)          20
 Word:arbitrary
 len(word)=           9
```

Comment: Why didn't you ever specify lun? You just set that to any number, right?

Comment: @GeneralPancake Very observant. The `newunit` specifier (from the 2008 standard) opens a file on an unused unit number, and returns the number chosen. I've assigned that value to `lun` so that the correct unit number can be accessed later using `read`.

Comment: So lun is automatically assigned when you write the open command?

Comment: Also it seems that I can't perform the read operation on an allocatable array. Meaning, basically, I can't read into an allocatable array. Why is that? This is personal, but I don't ever want to read into something that is required to be preallocated.

My assumption is that it's because the unallocated character string you're trying to read into has a length of zero, so read is working it's just trying to store into an array with, quite literally, zero spaces. Is there anyway to allocate dynamically? E.g. read in the number of characters or read in one character at a time and append, etc.?

Comment: A value is assigned to `lun` from `newunit`, which is a function that returns an unused unit number. It doesn't really matter what the value is in most cases, as long as you have a reference to it.

Comment: "read in the number of characters": That's basically what using `trim` after reading into the fixed-length character var is doing. "read in one character at a time and append": I suppose it's possible, but it sounds really inefficient and like it would just be a whole lotta code to write in Fortran.

Comment: And nope, you can't *read into* an unallocated character string...but you can *automatically allocate* on assignment (i.e, without the `allocate(...)` intrinsic). I guess that's the point of my answer :)  If that's unacceptable to you, I suppose you could just use the fixed-length character string and use `trim` and `len_trim` as needed. That works just as well and is probably a bit faster since there is no run-time allocation involved.

Comment: In Fortran you can create either character strings with a specified string length (ex: `character(len=5)::mystring`), or an array of *n* strings each of a specified length (ex: `character(len=5), dimension(N)::array_of_mystrings`). I generally only use the second option to be interoperable with C, using a length of 1 of course.

Comment: This discussion is getting a bit long. Final: `word(1:len_trim(word))` or simply `trim(word)` does the same without explicitly using a number or variable such as `m`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two questions in your one code, so let me address them first:

- **What is `iostat`?** -- `iostat` is an error code relating to the I/O statement. If everything worked fine, it will be set to `0`, if not, it will have a non-zero value. Examples on what could go wrong when trying to open a file:

  - File doesn't exist
  - Directory doesn't exist
  - User doesn't have permission to open the file
- **What is `(A)`?** -- This is the format string. `(A)` refers to a string of arbitrary length. See [here](https://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs201/NOTES/chap05/format.html) for more information

The code looks as if it should work, however the result isn't what you expect. There are two possibilities that spring to my mind:

1. The file you are trying to read doesn't exist, or doesn't exist in the directory that you are executing the program in, or you don't have the permission to read it. This results in `ierr` being set to a non-zero error code (corresponding to 'File not Found'). This results in the `do` loop not executing even once since the `ierr` isn't zero to start with.

   I recommend using the newer `iomsg` statement in addition to `iostat`. `iomsg` is a string that corresponds to a human-readable explanation to what went wrong.

   ```
   character(len=100) :: iomsg
   <snip>
   open(10, file=Filename, status='old', action='read',iostat=ierr, iomsg=iomsg)
   if (ierr /= 0) then
       print*, "Error opening file " // trim(Filename)
       print*, iomsg
       STOP 1
   end if
   ```
2. The file exist, but is empty. This would result in nothing being printed. Just check to be sure nothing has changed in the file.

Hint, both `iostat` and `iomsg` are available in all file I/O operations, so also for `read`, `write`, and even `close`. It can't hurt to use them.